# Playframework 2.6: How to launch a production build without the console?

Tags: playframework, production-environment, playframework-2.6

I'm using Play Framework 2.6. After creating the production build zip using

```
dist
```

In the play console, I'm using this code to launch the application on the server

```
my-first-app-1.0/bin/my-first-app -Dconfig.file=/path/to/config -Dplay.http.secret.key=$APP_SECRET
```

this launches a console that ends with :

```
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

after which my server proceeds to work perfectly fine. However, closing the console (`ctrl+C`) or exiting the terminal window; `ctrl+d` does nothing either. What am I missing here?

**update**

So I looked through the logs, but exactly nothing happens before the server shuts down.

```
2018-04-20 02:24:36,207 [INFO] from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-28 - <some benign application log>
2018-04-20 02:36:25,881 [INFO] from play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer in Thread-5 - Stopping server...
2018-04-20 02:36:25,940 [INFO] from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41 - Shutting down connection pool.
```

Of course, during this time my terminal had also disconnected (again, it seems to me that the way I'm starting my server is wrong, please advise.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seemed to indeed be that Play was quitting because of the console.

I managed to solve this by starting play using nohup:
`nohup ~/myApp/bin/myApp -Dconfig.file=/path/to/conf -Dplay.http.secret.key=$SECRET &`

Answer (score 1):

I need to say I don't have super senior level experience; but couple of things here; regarding the deployment of the Play application:

1. **Standalone app on a physical/virtual server**: If you want to deploy your application on bare metal/server instance/etc. without any other front facing applications, then you need to run your application on port `80` not `9000`. Because you want your users to go to `example.com` and not `example.com:9000`.
2. **Standalone app behind http server on physical/virtual server**: You could use [front end http server](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/HTTPServer) (e.g., Nginx) and run your Play application behind it. This way you can use the front-end http server as a bridge to your application. In fact, you can use it as a load balancer to multiple instances of the an application.
3. **Dockerizing your application**: This time, you make a docker image from your application, and put that image into a container management system (e.g., Kubernetes). Then you need to create a load balancer that directs the traffic from the public Internet to your container management system.
4. **Cloud Service Deployment**: There are also [cloud service deployments](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/DeployingCloud). For example, in Heroku, you use its plugin, as a dependency, within your `build.sbt`; and then you push your app into its structure, where the rest is being taken care of.

Number three is obviously an overkill for small teams; but it could be **the solution** to your problem where; you don't want to `ssh` into your server and deploy your Play application. The same with number four. For number one and two, you could however create a shell script that is executed based on a certain criteria (when your server is rebooted) to execute the Play related script; to bring up the application.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'm currently using an apache server that listens on the 80 port and uses <VirtualHost> to route traffic to the Play Server that's listening on 9000 (It's one of the ways described in your link) - however, after starting the server, a console display starts up - and exiting it causes the server to stop listening.

Comment: @vortexkd that is totally fine, in a case where the team is small; and also not so many users. However, if you want to make it scalable (more users, more read/write to your database, etc.), then you can look at the other options.

Comment: @vortexkd you could imagine if there is a problem in your app, lets say ate all the memory due to a memory leak; then you need to deal with killing/restarting/deploying, etc. In a container management system, such as kubernetes, the management system, does the killing/restarting/deploying the images into n number of instances (based on the rules defined by you) so it become much more manageable.

Comment: I also thought that it could be a memory issue - but it doesn't look like it (refer updated answer), though I haven't ruled it out entirely. Is there no equivalent to **play start** in version 2.6? I'm still pretty sure it's to do with the console as the shutdown has never happened while the console is connected.

Comment: @vortexkd how did you set your logs? Did you change its settings? Because now we just see the `INFO` level. Perhaps change it to the `DEBUG` level? For starting the app what about `sbt run`? Doesn't it cover your case?  By the way, I had an issue with memory, that was actually a memory leak; so that after a while the app would consume 1.5GB memory instead of 500. So, it is something that you need to look into the life cycle of your app. Get rid of any blocking code unless you have to; and inject your `ExecutionContext` instead of using the `Global` execution context; if you know what I mean.

Comment: So I managed to solve the issue by starting play inside nohup like this: `nohup ~/myApp/bin/myApp -Dconfig.file=/path/to/conf -Dplay.http.secret.key=$SECRET &` I'm going to add that as the answer here - thanks for your help!

Comment: @vortexkd no worries glad I could help. Ahaaa, still the issue is resolved using the Linux command! Good luck.